# Amp stops buzzing when I unplug guitar

Tags: electric-guitar, amplifiers, buzz

Loud buzzing just started to happen with guitar plugged in. As soon as I unplug the guitar the amp stops the buzz and peace returns. I’ve checked the leads so I’m wondering what’s happening with the guitar? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I’m wondering if this is a very indirect way of saying the guitar buzzes? Could you confirm that this happens with different guitars?

Comment: The cable between guitar and amp is a shielded instrument cable right? PA speaker cables for passive speakers look like instrument cables and will cause buzz if plugged to a guitar and amp.  Try a new guitar cable, then another guitar.

Comment: You might also try turning out the lights to see if the guitar is picking up noise from them.